# SQL database is taking up 1.5 TB but only using about 1 TB

Tags: disk-space, azure-sql-managed-instance

SQL Server is almost 98% full. Its one database is taking up 1.5 TB but only using about 1 TB. Can we get any of that space back, if so, how? We are using Azure SQL Managed Instance.

**File Growth Options**:

- File Growth: 16MB
- Maximum File size: Unlimited

**Remarks**:

1. It's a data warehouse MS Azure project with lots of users (none of them SQL experts). Log size is about 75GB with same growth rate.
2. This database has several tables of about 10-15GB sizes that often go through the data operations of kill and fill.

Comment: Did someone delete a lot of data, or drop a table?  Also, there should be a Standard Report in SSMS to show a database's files' sizes and used vs free space.

Comment: You can get the space back, but the large size may be intentional.  In Azure SQL Managed Instances, your disk performance is related to how big your database files are set to be.  I have mine set to almost 2x their strict requirements because I need the disk throughput that gives me.

Comment: The shrink command is available for MI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-file?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @RonJohn To answer you question, I added item 2 in Remarks section.

Answer (score 1):

> This database has several tables of about 10-15GB sizes that often go
> through the data operations of kill and fill.

One possibility is that some "fills" are bigger than others.  Thus,  you'll see lots of free space if there *were* many large fills while the recent "fills" have been smaller.

Since 1.5TB s 50% larger than 1.0TB, and 15GB is 50% larger than 10GB, the math even works.

Comment: What would then be a possible solution to get some of the space back, any suggestions?

Comment: @nam in bog standard SQL Server, you’d use DBCC SHRINKFILE.  Investigate whether there’s something like that in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

we were in similar situation and were asked by microsoft to run the following command

```
SELECT name,
    CurrentSizeMB = size / 128.0,
    SpaceUsed = CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT) / 128.0
    , size / 128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT) / 128.0 AS AvailableSpaceInMB
FROM sys.database_files;
```

find the file name from above query

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (filename, size in mb to shrink);

GO
```